# Curl Post using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, post, sms-gateway

This is mi First Post on Stackoverflow.
I need to do a Curl Post to an SMS Gateway with PHP but I´d never done it, the manual says I  should do something like this

```
curl -u admin:admin -d '{"text":"Hello.","port":[0],"param":[{"number":"123456","text_param":["John"],"user_id":1}]}’ –H "Content-Type:
application/json" http://192.168.1.252/api/send_sms
```

```
#I  tried some users  post, but I  can´t get to get it working. 
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$username='admin';
$password='admin';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.252/api/send_sms");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = array(
        'text' => "TEXT TO BE SEND",
        'port' => 0,
        'number'=>"123456",
        'text_param'=>"John",
        'user_id'=>1
     );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

#Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
curl_close ($ch);


#Further processing ...


if ($server_output == "OK") { echo "OK"; } else { echo "FAILED"; }
?>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error you are getting if any.

Comment: In data, number text_param and user_id are inside an element called param. Restructure your $data variable so that those 3 elements are as so "param": ["number" => 123, // text_param and user_id ]

Comment: thanks iJamesPHP2 ,   I done  this      `$data = array(
        'text' => "PRUEBA",
        'port' => 0,
  'param': ["number" => 123456 ,"text_param"=>"John" , 'user_id'=>"1"]  
     );    `     I`m not  shure I  I  have to encode it  with json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it,

Thanks a lot  anyway.  I  added content type with

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json'));
and redone the  $data  to meat specs.

Thanks